# How do I select the text in a TextBox?

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I found that it's quite easy with nsDialogs to set the focus to a specific control:

```
${NSD_SETFOCUS} $myHWnd
```

But is there also a way to select all the text in that control, so that when the user starts typing, what is already there is overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's also quite easy using the standard NSIS function `SendMessage`. You can simply send the EM_SETSEL  message with 0 and -1 as parameters:

```
SendMessage $myHWnd ${EM_SETSEL} 0 -1
```

This will select all the text in the textbox.